# how to get auto generated id when data set on firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to get doc when creating set data?

```
  Future<void> addVehicleCategory(VehicleCategoryModel model) {
    return _db.collection('vehicle').document().setData({
      'docId': //to Here
      'createdAt':DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      'serverTimestamp':FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_db.collection('vehicle').document()` with no arguments immediately returns a DocumentReference that has a random ID, computed on the client.  The document has not been written yet, but the ID is available.  You can use that ID to write the field on the new document, specifying the document ID directly:

```
DocumentReference ref = _db.collection('vehicle').document()
return ref.setData(
      'docId': ref.documentID
      ...
));
```

See also the solution for swift: [Add a Document's Document ID to Its Own Firestore Document - Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301325/add-a-documents-document-id-to-its-own-firestore-document-swift-4)